# JavaFX ListView IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, listview, javafx, indexoutofboundsexception, simplify

I am using a JFXListView for geting a list of services from a remote server using rmi, when i refresh the JFXListView i just call the method getServices, the problem is after activating the refresh method it runs instantly instead of taking the refresh rate (time between each refresh) from the JFXSlider and after a few refreshes the application is blocked and i get

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 8, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433)
    at javafxcyberwind.UtilisateurController.getServices(UtilisateurController.java:172)
    at javafxcyberwind.UtilisateurController.lambda$Refresh$14(UtilisateurController.java:420)
    at com.sun.scenario.animation.shared.TimelineClipCore.visitKeyFrame(TimelineClipCore.java:239)
    at com.sun.scenario.animation.shared.TimelineClipCore.playTo(TimelineClipCore.java:180)
    at javafx.animation.Timeline.impl_playTo(Timeline.java:176)
    at javafx.animation.AnimationAccessorImpl.playTo(AnimationAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at com.sun.scenario.animation.shared.InfiniteClipEnvelope.timePulse(InfiniteClipEnvelope.java:110)
    at javafx.animation.Animation.impl_timePulse(Animation.java:1102)
    at javafx.animation.Animation$1.lambda$timePulse$25(Animation.java:186)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.animation.Animation$1.timePulse(Animation.java:185)
    at com.sun.scenario.animation.AbstractMasterTimer.timePulseImpl(AbstractMasterTimer.java:344)
    at com.sun.scenario.animation.AbstractMasterTimer$MainLoop.run(AbstractMasterTimer.java:267)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:514)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulseFromQueue(QuantumToolkit.java:491)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$403(QuantumToolkit.java:319)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

, i think this is due to that the method getServices is much charged. How can i simplify as much as possible this method ?

```
@FXML
private JFXListView li_se;

@FXML
private JFXSlider refresh;    

@FXML
public void getServices(ActionEvent e) {
    try {
        li_se.getItems().clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < R.ListeService().size(); i++) {
            JFXButton b = new JFXButton("" + R.ListeService().get(i));//line that is pointed by the IndexOutOfBoundsException
            b.setStyle("-fx-rippler-fill:black;-fx-text-fill:black;-fx-font-size:16px;-fx-background-color:orange;-fx-background-radius:5px;");
            b.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
                try {
                    VBox vBox = new VBox(10);
                    JFXListView li_par = new JFXListView();
                    JFXTextField[] fields = new JFXTextField[22];
                    TextFieldEntier[] fEntiers = new TextFieldEntier[22];
                    TextFieldReel[] fRéels = new TextFieldReel[22];
                    ChoiceBox<String> choiceBox = new ChoiceBox<>();
                    choiceBox.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/choise-box.css").toExternalForm());
                    choiceBox.getItems().addAll("true", "false");
                    ArrayList<Object> tab = new ArrayList<>();
                    JFXButton folder = new JFXButton("Ouvrir le répertoire");
                    folder.setDisable(true);
                    ObservableList<String> ListParam = FXCollections.observableArrayList(R.paramService(b.getText()));
                    JFXDialogLayout content = new JFXDialogLayout();
                    content.setHeading(new Text(b.getText()));
                    content.setBody(vBox);
                    JFXDialog dialog = new JFXDialog(st_dl, content, JFXDialog.DialogTransition.CENTER);
                    k = 0;
                    ListParam.stream().map((st) -> {
                        if (st.equals("double")) {
                            fRéels[k] = new TextFieldReel();
                            fRéels[k].setPadding(new Insets(11));
                            Label lb = new Label("Argument ( Réel ) : ");
                            lb.setPadding(new Insets(7));
                            lb.setStyle("-fx-min-Width:178;-fx-text-fill:white;-fx-background-color:orange;-fx-background-radius:5px;");
                            HBox hb = new HBox(10);
                            hb.getChildren().add(lb);
                            hb.getChildren().add(fRéels[k]);
                            li_par.getItems().add(hb);
                        }
                        return st;
                    }).map((st) -> {
                        if (st.equals("java.lang.String")) {
                            fields[k] = new JFXTextField();
                            fields[k].setMinHeight(35);
                            fields[k].setMinWidth(157);
                            Label lb = new Label("Argument ( Texte ) : ");
                            lb.setMinWidth(178);
                            lb.setPadding(new Insets(7));
                            lb.setStyle("-fx-text-fill:white;-fx-background-color:orange;-fx-background-radius:5px;");
                            HBox hb = new HBox(10);
                            hb.getChildren().add(lb);
                            hb.getChildren().add(fRéels[k]);
                            li_par.getItems().add(hb);
                        }
                        return st;
                    }).map((st) -> {
                        if (st.equals("int")) {
                            fEntiers[k] = new TextFieldEntier();
                            fEntiers[k].setPadding(new Insets(11));
                            Label lb = new Label("Argument ( Entier ) : ");
                            lb.setPadding(new Insets(7));
                            lb.setStyle("-fx-min-Width:178;-fx-text-fill:white;-fx-background-color:orange;-fx-background-radius:5px;");
                            HBox hb = new HBox(10);
                            hb.getChildren().add(lb);
                            hb.getChildren().add(fEntiers[k]);
                            li_par.getItems().add(hb);
                        }
                        return st;
                    }).map((st) -> {
                        if (st.equals("boolean")) {
                            Label lb = new Label("Argument ( " + st + " ) : ");
                            lb.setMinWidth(178);
                            lb.setPadding(new Insets(7));
                            lb.setStyle("-fx-text-fill:white;-fx-background-color:orange;-fx-background-radius:5px;");
                            HBox hb = new HBox(10);
                            hb.getChildren().add(lb);
                            hb.getChildren().add(choiceBox);
                            li_par.getItems().add(hb);
                        }
                        return st;
                    }).map((st) -> {
                        if (st.equals("java.io.File")) {
                            fields[k] = new JFXTextField();
                            fields[k].setMinHeight(35);
                            fields[k].setMinWidth(157);
                            Label lb = new Label("Argument ( Fichier ) : ");
                            lb.setMinWidth(178);
                            lb.setPadding(new Insets(7));
                            lb.setStyle("-fx-text-fill:white;-fx-background-color:orange;-fx-background-radius:5px;");
                            HBox hb = new HBox(10);
                            hb.getChildren().add(lb);
                            hb.getChildren().add(fields[k]);
                            li_par.getItems().add(hb);
                            int x = k;
                            fields[k].addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, (javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent e1) -> {
                                FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
                                selectedFile = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
                                if (selectedFile != null) {
                                    fields[x].setText(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        return st;
                    }).forEachOrdered((_item) -> {
                        k++;
                    });
                    JFXButton exe = new JFXButton("Exécuter");
                    WeatherIconView weatherIcon = new WeatherIconView(WeatherIcon.CLOUD);
                    weatherIcon.setSize("30");
                    weatherIcon.setFill(Color.DODGERBLUE);
                    exe.setGraphic(weatherIcon);
                    exe.setStyle("-fx-text-fill:DODGERBLUE;-fx-background-color:white;-fx-background-radius:5px;");
                    exe.setPadding(new Insets(10));
                    JFXTextField res = new JFXTextField();
                    res.setMinWidth(150);
                    Label re = new Label("Résultat");
                    HBox hb = new HBox(10);
                    hb.getChildren().add(re);
                    hb.getChildren().add(res);
                    hb.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
                    hb.getChildren().add(folder);
                    li_par.setMaxHeight(180);
                    li_par.setMinWidth(384);
                    vBox.getChildren().add(li_par);
                    vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
                    vBox.getChildren().add(exe);
                    vBox.getChildren().add(hb);
                    exe.setOnAction((ActionEvent e2) -> {
                        tab.clear();
                        try {
                            int k1 = 0;
                            for (String st : ListParam) {
                                if (st.equals("int")) {
                                    tab.add(Integer.valueOf(fEntiers[k1].getText()));
                                }
                                if (st.equals("double")) {
                                    tab.add(Double.valueOf(fRéels[k1].getText()));
                                }
                                if (st.equals("boolean")) {
                                    tab.add(Boolean.valueOf(choiceBox.getValue()));
                                }
                                if (st.equals("java.lang.String")) {
                                    tab.add(fields[k1].getText());
                                }
                                if (st.equals("java.io.File")) {
                                    Fichier f = new Fichier(selectedFile.getName());
                                    tab.add(f);
                                    p1 = (int) ((Math.random() * (9000 - 5000)) + 5000);
                                    R.uploadToCloud(p1, selectedFile.getName());
                                    Socket s = new Socket(ip.IPserveur(), p1);
                                    ObjectOutputStream out;
                                    FileInputStream inf = new FileInputStream(new File(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath()));
                                    out = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                                    byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
                                    int n;
                                    while ((n = inf.read(buf)) != -1) {
                                        out.write(buf, 0, n);
                                    }
                                    out.close();
                                }
                                k1++;
                            }
                            if (R.retourService(b.getText()).equals("int") || R.retourService(b.getText()).equals("double") || R.retourService(b.getText()).equals("boolean") || R.retourService(b.getText()).equals("class java.lang.String")) {
                                R.envoieDemande(b.getText(), "", 0, tab.toArray());
                                res.setText("" + R.getResult());
                            }
                            if (R.retourService(b.getText()).equals("class java.io.File")) {
                                p1 = (int) ((Math.random() * (9000 - 5000)) + 5000);
                                LocateRegistry.createRegistry(p1);
                                Utilisateur_MethodsPAIRIMPL U = new Utilisateur_MethodsPAIRIMPL();
                                Naming.bind("rmi://" + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress() + ":" + p1 + "/" + R.getEmail(), U);
                                R.envoieDemande(b.getText(), InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress(), p1, tab.toArray());
                                res.setText("C:/Utilisateur/" + R.getResfile());
                                folder.setDisable(false);
                            }
                        } catch (RemoteException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
                            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
                            alert.setTitle("Erreur");
                            alert.setHeaderText("Erreur");
                            alert.setContentText("Veuillez choisir une option");
                            ButtonType btn_annuler = new ButtonType("Annuler");
                            ButtonType btn_réessayer = new ButtonType("Réessayer");
                            alert.setGraphic(new ImageView("icon/erreur.png"));
                            alert.getButtonTypes().setAll(btn_réessayer, btn_annuler);
                            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
                            ex.printStackTrace(pw);
                            TextArea area = new TextArea(sw.toString());
                            alert.getDialogPane().setExpandableContent(area);
                            Stage stage = (Stage) alert.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow();
                            stage.getIcons().add(new Image("icon/erreur.png"));
                            Optional<ButtonType> res1 = alert.showAndWait();
                            if (res1.get() == btn_réessayer) {
                                alert.close();
                            }
                            if (res1.get() == btn_annuler) {
                                dialog.close();
                                alert.close();
                            }
                            //Logger.getLogger(UtilisateurController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        } catch (IOException | AlreadyBoundException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(UtilisateurController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                    });
                    JFXButton button = new JFXButton("Terminer " + b.getText());
                    button.setOnAction((ActionEvent evt) -> {
                        dialog.close();
                    });
                    content.setActions(button);
                    dialog.setOverlayClose(false);
                    dialog.show();
                    dialog.setOnDialogOpened((evt) -> {
                        t = true;
                        property.set(1);
                        bp.set(true);
                        pn_li.setDisable(true);
                        pn_us.setDisable(true);
                    });
                    dialog.setOnDialogClosed((evt) -> {
                        pn_li.setDisable(false);
                        pn_us.setDisable(false);
                        bp.set(false);
                        property.set(0);
                    });
                    folder.setOnAction((ActionEvent evt) -> {
                        try {
                            Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(urep));
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(UtilisateurController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                    });
                } catch (RemoteException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(UtilisateurController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            });
            li_se.getItems().add(b);
        }
        if (!li_se.isExpanded()) {
            li_se.setExpanded(true);
            li_se.depthProperty().set(1);
        } else {
            /*li_se.setExpanded(false);
            li_se.depthProperty().set(0);*/
        }
        lb_re.setDisable(false);
        refresh.setDisable(false);
        //bp.bind(property.isEqualTo(1));
    } catch (RemoteException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(UtilisateurController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

The rest of the code is :

```
package javafxcyberwind;

import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXListView;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXSlider;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableNumberValue;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.effect.BoxBlur;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.CycleMethod;
import javafx.scene.paint.LinearGradient;
import javafx.scene.paint.Stop;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.util.Duration;

/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author Sami
 */
public class UtilisateurController implements Initializable, ControlledScreen, ChangeListener {

    ScreensController myController;

    @FXML
    private JFXListView li_se;

    @FXML
    private StackPane st_dl, glass;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane pn_us, pn_li;

    @FXML
    private Rectangle rec;

    @FXML
    private JFXSlider refresh;

    @FXML
    private Label lb_re;

    ServerSocket sv;
    private int p1, k;
    IP ip = new IP();
    File selectedFile;
    boolean t = false;
    private final String urep = "c:/Utilisateur/";
    private BooleanProperty bp = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     *
     * @param url
     * @param rb
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        File p = new File(urep);
        p.mkdir();
        String[] entries = p.list();
        for (String s : entries) {
            File currentFile = new File(p.getPath(), s);
            currentFile.delete();
        }
        li_se.getItems().clear();
        glass.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);");
        BoxBlur blur = new BoxBlur(10, 10, 3);
        glass.setEffect(blur);
        refresh.valueProperty().addListener(this);
        Timeline timeline;
        double widthOfOneGradientCycle = 40.0;
        double gradientSlopeDegree = 45.0;
        double xStartStatic = 100.0;
        double yStartStatic = 100.0;
        double xEndStatic = xStartStatic + (widthOfOneGradientCycle * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(gradientSlopeDegree)));
        double yEndStatic = yStartStatic + (widthOfOneGradientCycle * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(gradientSlopeDegree)));
        timeline = new Timeline();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            int innerIterator = i;
            KeyFrame kf = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(40 * innerIterator), (ActionEvent ae) -> {
                double runningRadius = innerIterator * (widthOfOneGradientCycle / 10);
                double xStartDynamic = xStartStatic + (runningRadius * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(gradientSlopeDegree)));
                double yStartDynamic = yStartStatic + (runningRadius * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(gradientSlopeDegree)));
                double xEndDynamic = xEndStatic + (runningRadius * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(gradientSlopeDegree)));
                double yEnddynamic = yEndStatic + (runningRadius * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(gradientSlopeDegree)));

                LinearGradient gradient = new LinearGradient(xStartDynamic, yStartDynamic, xEndDynamic, yEnddynamic,
                        false, CycleMethod.REPEAT, new Stop[]{
                            new Stop(0.0, Color.TRANSPARENT),
                            new Stop(0.5, Color.TRANSPARENT),
                            new Stop(1.0, Color.BLACK)
                        });
                rec.setStroke(gradient);
            });
            timeline.getKeyFrames().add(kf);
        }
        timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        timeline.play();
    }

    private void Refresh(ObservableNumberValue refreshRateProperty) {
        Timeline refreshWonder = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), (ActionEvent event) -> {
            //getServices(event);
        }));
        refreshWonder.rateProperty().bind(Bindings.divide(1d, refreshRateProperty));
        refreshWonder.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);

        bp.addListener((o, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue) {
                refreshWonder.pause();
            } else {
                refreshWonder.play();
            }
        });

        refreshWonder.play();
    }

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
        int r = ((int) refresh.getValue());
        ObservableNumberValue obsInt = new SimpleIntegerProperty(r);
        Refresh(obsInt);
    }

    @Override
    public void setScreenParent(ScreensController screenParent) {
        myController = screenParent;
    }

    @FXML
    private void Back(ActionEvent e) {
        myController.setScreen(ScreensFramework.screen2ID);
        li_se.getItems().clear();
    }

    @FXML
    private void Fermer(ActionEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

That's the ListeService() method :

```
@Override
public ArrayList ListeService() throws RemoteException {
    ArrayList<String> se = new ArrayList<>();
    se.clear();
    try {
        Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.2:3306/Cyberwind", "cloud", "");
        Statement sta = c.createStatement();
        ResultSet res = sta.executeQuery("SELECT `service` FROM `connexion`");
        ArrayList<String> uniques = new ArrayList<>();
        while (res.next() && !res.getString("service").equals("null")) {
            uniques.add(res.getString("service"));
        }
        uniques.stream().filter((re) -> (!se.contains(re))).forEachOrdered((re) -> {
            se.add(re);
        });
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Cloud_ServeurIMPL.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return se;
}
```

Comment: `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is not an error about memory. For instance `OutOfMemoryError` is.

Comment: The problem is in the refresh method it runs instantly.